# If condition to check value of multiple column array php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get value of `is_activated` column key. But can not get the exact value. Have tried `array_search()`

Review the array

Need to check value of all `is_activated` key whether it's value is 1 or not.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    [first_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => john 
            )

        [is_activated] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (

        [first_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => mark
            )
        [is_activated] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (

        [first_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => pretik
            )
        [is_activated] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )
    )

)
```

I have tried this below solution but can can not get result.

```
$is_user_activated = array_search(1,array_column($activity,'is_activated'));

if($is_user_activated == 1) { echo 'yes'; }
else { echo 'no'; }
```

Comment: `is_activated` column's value is __array__

Comment: Yes that's why i am stuck over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `array_filter()` for such tasks, it allows to use a callback filter function:

```
<?php
$data = [
    [
        'first_name' => ['john'] ,
        'is_activated' => [0]
    ],
    [
        'first_name' => ['mark'],
        'is_activated' => [1]
    ],
    [
        'first_name' => ['pretik'],
        'is_activated' => [0]
    ]
];
$matches = array_filter($data, function($entry) {
    return in_array(1, $entry['is_activated']);
});
var_dump($matches);
```

The output of that is:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["first_name"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "mark"
    }
    ["is_activated"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Reason why that is a bit awkward is that your initial data has a very strange structure: the values of the elements are *arrays* themselves holding the actual values instead of scalar values themselves. That makes searching more complex than in "normal" situations. So take a good look if maybe you can fix that strange structure instead to be able to use an easier search approach.

Comment: Yes the structure is very complected ... is there any way to make it like this way  `$records = array(
    array(
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
);`

Comment: And how should i compare your output array value with if condition ; like 'is_activated' value = 1 or not ?

Comment: About your first comment: you mean you want to change the structure of the data you already have? Certainly the structure you now here suggests is possible and actually makes much more sense. But I do not know where you get that data from, nor how you prepare it for this search.

Comment: About your second comment: obviously you want to replace the condition `in_array(1, $entry['is_activated'])` with `1==$entry['is_activated']` or simply `$entry['is_activated']` by itself.

Comment: It is the wordpress data that i got it from wordpress hook get_user_meta()

Comment: Ok, so that structure is fixed, nothing you can easily change without modifying the wordpress code, which you do not want to do. So you have three options: keep things as they are and go with the search solution I posted, or do the same search but then create a custom, simplified result array from the hit you got or you first convert the structure you receive using something like `array_walk()`. I would go with the first choice, probably.

Comment: Awesome -- this works perfectly! The other answers are very much appreciated too, but this is simple and works perfectly. I was close on my own, but wouldn't have made it otherwise. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to be doing this in a loop rather than using array_search. Use a foreach() to get your desired result:

```
foreach($yourArray as $item) {
    if($item['is_activated'][0] == 1) {
        echo 'yes';
    } else {
        echo 'no';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the activated users via [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$activated = array_filter($users, function($record) {
    return reset($record['is_activated']) == 1;
});
```

This will only keep users who are activated, you can then simply count the array to see if you have any activated users:

```
echo count($activated) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Example here: http://ideone.com/mMuJcO